# 2 Dimensional Char Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there such a way to initialize a char array and then loop through them all and change the value? I'm trying to create a table like structure.

I just keep getting errors like "Cannot initialize a value of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [3]'.

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 for development

```
int width = 25;
int height = 50;


char board [50][25] = {""}; // height x width

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < height; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            board[i][j] = {"||"};
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Each element in your 2D array is a single `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `board[i][j] = {"||"};` . The string `"||"` cannot be implicitly converted to a single character.

It's not clear what you are trying to do; each cell of the board is a `char`, and `||` is two chars.  Two doesn't go into one. Perhaps you meant:

```
board[i][j] = '|';
```

---

Also, your loop nesting is backwards (the `height` loop should be the outer one). The indexing of an array is the same as its declaration, so for `board[i][j]` to work when the declaration was `char board[50][25]`,  `i` must be ranging from `0` to `49` .

An improvement would be:

```
int const width = 25;
int const height = 50;
char board[height][width] = {};

for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the characters in the array with single quotes, not double. So:

```
board[i][j] = '|';
```

Also, notice that you can only put a single character in each position